# Changes stay on Failed Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins

In my Jenkins pipeline I do a checkout, after that checkout something happens that causes the build to fail. The changes/commits stay attached to that failed build.  The next build doesn't show the changes that were reported on the failed build.  From the below I would like to see the 3 commits to show on build #76.

[image]

Comment: That seems like an odd request. The changes are logically on #75, not #76 -- why would you want them on 76?

Comment: You can write some custom changeset handling if you want by changing `currentBuild.changesets`. I remember having to do that with some janky pipeline we had to write with multiple checkouts that didn't preserve changelogs from the earlier checkouts. It was a giant pain though -- strongly recommend not doing that :D

Comment: @AdamSmith Because Build #75 failed.  The auditors like seeing the commits that were attached to each build.  Will have to explain to them that failed builds will just be this way.  hopefully won't happen to frequently in normal use.

Comment: What triggers #76? If you're rebuilding 75 due to some ephemeral issue, you should be able to use the Rebuilder plugin to do so with better breadcrumbs https://plugins.jenkins.io/rebuild/